# How to avoid duplicate rows with junction table. (How to use it)?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Since a song can have several songwriters and a songwriter can write several songs I have created a junction-table `songwriter_track`. But I'm not sure how to "combine it" with my ordinary `track` table. I want to be able to select attributes from my `track` table and at the same time get the songwriters of the song. But unfortunately my current solution returns duplicates of songs. What I'm I doing wrong? Is there a way to solve this? Do I have to run two queries?

Here's my tables:

```
   TABLE track(
         track_id     INT PRIMARY KEY
         track_title       VARCHAR(100)
         track_duration    VARCHAR(100)
         lyric_url         VARCHAR(150))

  TABLE songwriter(
        songwriter_id INT  PRIMARY KEY
        songwriter_name VARCHAR(30)  
        UNIQUE INDEX (songwriter_name))

  TABLE songwriter_track(
        id_songwriter INT REFERENCES songwriter(songwriter_id)
        id_track      INT REFERENCES track(track_id)
        PRIMARY KEY (id_songwriter, id_track))


 VIEW `tracks_view` AS "
      "SELECT t.*, s.songwriter_name  "
           "FROM track t "
           "INNER JOIN songwriter_track st "
           "ON t.track_id = st.id_track "
           "INNER JOIN songwriter s "
           "ON s.songwriter_id = st.id_songwriter;";
```

Comment: What do "tracks" have to do with songwriters?  "tracks" have a song, but I think songs have songwriters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A track/song have songwriters.

Comment: @LarsLogik: so what would be your expected result? For each song, we can put all the songwriters in a column as a comma-separated list, would that be OK?

Comment: Also, can you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: oracle, mysql, sql-server...?

Comment: @LarsLogik . . . A "track" is not a "song".  A "track" is a particular recording of a song on an "album" (at least as I understand these terms in English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate just one record per track, one solution would be to  put all the songwriters in a column as a comma-separated list.

Consider:

```
select 
    t.track_id, 
    t.track_title, 
    t.track_duration, 
    t.lyric_url,
    group_concat(s.songwriter_name order by s.songwriter_name) songwriters
from track t
inner join songwriter_track st on st.id_track = t.track_id
inner join songwriter s on s.songwriter_id = sr.id_songwriter
group by 
    t.track_id, 
    t.track_title, 
    t.track_duration, 
    t.lyric_url
```